# plugin manager goes wrong when i activate my plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have made my first wordpress plugin (share me), to share posts with different social networks.
But when I activate it, the plugin manager goes wrong! like you can see in the screen-shot below.

When my plugin is disable 
[image]

And when i activate it !

[image: Wp plugin manager]

This is the plugin description:

```
<?php
      /*
          Plugin Name: Share-me
          Description: Share posts on differents Social Networks
          Author: Me
          Version: 1.0.1
         */
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this plugin header. What are those `...`?

Comment: nothing a just add this here !

Comment: did you see the screenshot ?

Comment: I got the same porblem with "Twenty Twelve" and "Twenty Eleven" themes

Comment: yes i removed it to avoid google ...

Comment: i updated my post with a screenshot with disable plugin

Comment: Out of options, short of re-installing WP... Check if your config and htaccess don't have anything weird

Comment: this is my 3rd WP install and each time every thing is ok, and when i activate my plugin i have this... thank you any way

Comment: Crate another plugin, maybe is the php file encoding? What about akismet?